# Modern Linux UI to work with Virtual Box Seamless mode

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtualbox, seamless

I'm having trouble finding a current linux distro with a desktop that works with Virtualbox [Seamless mode](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/virtualboxs-seamless-mode-combine-operating-systems-desktop/) on a windows7 host. I used to do it all the time with Gnome2, but most modern UI/Window manager frameworks either don't work with Seamless at all (the task bar doesn't appear), or lately, cause the Virtualbox host process to crash (looks like an issue with window resizing from the logs I can find).

I've tried Gnome3, Unity, and Cinnamon, which don't work at all, and MATE which had worked previously displays, but crashes regularly due to random input gestures (last crash happened as I was trying to allow stackexchange in noscript).

So, What modern linux UIs Do work with VirtualBox Seamless mode?

Comment: Have you tried some of the simpler ones like openbox, fluxbox, xfce, windowmaker?

Comment: No, since I generally try to avoid project spin-offs, and I don;t know of any projects that use them as the primary desktop offering, but I'll see how xfce works these days. never tried the others either as VM or bare metal install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the exact same plan with my new computer, and I seem to have succeeded with [Linux Mint 15 with Xfce](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=141). I am running Windows 8.1 Pro with VirtualBox 4.3.2 in seamless mode, and everything seems to work perfectly, so far. (Well, obviously, the seamless mode has its limitations, but I am able to live with them, while it provides a lot of value, running Linux and Windows at the same time.)

[image: Screenshot of my working desktop]

Comment: Very kewl! I'll give it a try. I had hoped for something a little flashier than xfce, but hey, function over form.

Comment: I'm actually finding now that the MATE version that ships with Mint 16 works without crashing. Thanks!